# Creating a Format File For Bulk import

Tags: sql-server, bcp, bulk

So when I try implementing this query:

```
BCP -SMSSQLSERVER01.[Internal_Checks].[Jan_Flat] format out  ^
-fC:\Desktop\exported data\Jan_FlatFormat.fmt -c -T  -UUGmn91 -SMSSQLSERVER01 -PChan
```

I am getting an error "A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options."

I want to create a Format File to bulk upload data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is -f for? You can use simple bcp as --> bcp master.dbo.table_name out C:\tempdb\export.dat -c -Ulogin -Sserver_name -Ppassword

Comment: -f is for format

Comment: If i Remove "format" after table name and -f then its giving me error of unknown argument"data\jan_FlatFormat.fmt"